# Can you include anything describing invention disclosures on your resume that have not been filed yet?

Tags: patent-infringement

The company I work for might fold in the next couple months... So I'm searching for other opportunities in preparation for that possibility.

I've submitted multiple invention disclosures to patent attorneys internally, but the process takes a while and they have not been filed yet (and truthfully may not be filed before the company folds).

Am I completely out of luck with being able to have on my resume that I've submitted invention disclosures along with any kind of meaningful description that might communicate the quality of the invention?

If I'm not out of luck, what is the correct way to format something like this?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly mention in a resume that you submitted multiple invention disclosures. However, I would avoid mentioning anything related to what the invention is or does. Part of this is legal in that public disclosure before filing could negatively impact the ability to obtain a patent. Beyond that, you most likely have a duty not to disclose private company information. You really do want to keep on good terms with your current company regardless of your long term plans. If you end up leaving and they continue to pursue the patents, you'll be able to take credit for your contributions.

Comment: Even if the company folds its assets might be bought by another company. Depending on the title of the application  it might be ok to disclose it.  Certainly you can disclose the field they are in.